# Bash Rsync: Is there a way to improve progress bar accuracy?

Tags: bash

So when trying to show progress while copying a directory, rsync seems to be the way to go. I've tried pv, but it slows down performance a lot.

Anyway, my goal is to have a unified progress bar for the entire directory transfer, which rsync does very well with --info=progress2 in the newer versions. The problem is that this progress bar is very inaccurate. It jumps up to 60-70% right away, and then slowly increases from there, climbing to 80-90% before dropping down, then climbing again, etc etc.

I was wondering if there are any options I can use with rsync to improve this? I'm open to ideas, say having it track the number of files copied vs bytes or something like that. I just ultimately want to make rsync's progress bar closer to an accurate representation of how far along in the process it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the `--no-i-r` option given the request.

This might not give you an *accurate* bar (it may jump) ... but it's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

No. rsync never scans the whole tree before operation, it reads directory contents on the fly. This is described in the `rsync(1)` man page under the `--progress` argument.

Comment: hmm... so is there any better option than rsync? I'm trying to have a progress bar for a large copy/paste operation, I've been scouring the web and rsync is the best that I've found so far.

Comment: You could perform a `rsync -n` first in order to capture the tree it will traverse, and then run it again normally for the actual progress.